# Java compatibility roadmap

Tags: vespa

Now that Java is on a shorter release cadence, is there a roadmap for supporting Vespa builds on Java 9, 10, etc?. I've also noticed that the Vespa build process hangs when using newer versions of Maven (3.5+).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the latest production ready Java release. However, Java 9 is special and will require a major release of Vespa (to 7). That will happen in Q3.

I run maven 3.5.2 and have never seen it hang (not since 3.2). Create a ticket on github with more information if you need help with that one.

Answer (score 2):

Multithreaded builds may deadlock when using 3.5.2 due to this Maven bug: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-6323

Please use at least Maven 3.5.3 if you're building with multiple threads (`-T` flag).